# Can I improve the response time of this login service application by making parts of it asynchronous?

Tags: python, sqlite, security, asynchronous, tornado

I have just written user login and logout but im trying to figure out what the most correct way of doing this is. From the documentation, there seems to be ways to make some of the code asynchronous, do i really need to do this? I've included the hashing functions (which i got from stackoverflow) so this is complete and can be built upon for very simple applications.

```
import os
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import binascii
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
from tornado.options import define, options


define('port', default=80, help='port to listen on')

settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    debug=True,
    cookie_secret="changethis",
    login_url="/login",
    # xsrf_cookies=True,
)

def hash_password(password):
    """Hash a password for storing."""
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password.encode('utf-8'), 
                                salt, 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash)
    return (salt + pwdhash).decode('ascii')

def verify_password(stored_password, provided_password):
    """Verify a stored password against one provided by user"""
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', 
                    provided_password.encode('utf-8'), 
                    salt.encode('ascii'), 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash).decode('ascii')
    return pwdhash == stored_password

try:
    db = sqlite3.connect('file:aaa.db?mode=rw', uri=True)
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    db = sqlite3.connect("aaa.db")
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE Users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, password TEXT NOT NULL);")

class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("session")

class IndexHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.current_user:
            self.write("not logged in")
            return
        count = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users;").fetchone()
        self.write('{} users so far!'.format(count[0]))

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        self.render("login.html")
    def post(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        name=self.get_body_argument("username")
        query= db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = ?;", (name,)).fetchone()
        if query[0] == 0:
            self.write("user does not exist")
        else:
            hashed_password = db.execute("SELECT (password) FROM Users WHERE username = ?;", (name,)).fetchone()[0]
            if verify_password(hashed_password, self.get_body_argument("password")):
                self.set_secure_cookie("session", name)
                self.write("cookie set, logged in")
            else:
                self.write("wrong password")

class SignupHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        self.render("signup.html")
    def post(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        name=self.get_body_argument("username")
        password=self.get_body_argument("password")
        try:
            with db:
                db.execute("INSERT INTO Users(username,password) VALUES (?,?);", (name, hash_password(password)))
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            self.write("user exists")
            return
        self.write("user added")

class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("session")
        self.write("logged out")

def main():
    routes=(
            (r'/', IndexHandler),
            (r'/login', LoginHandler),
            (r'/logout', LogoutHandler),
            (r'/signup', SignupHandler),
        )
    app = Application(routes, **settings)
    app.listen(options.port)
    IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please try to improve the focus of your question so it is answerable here. If want people to review your code, take it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: any suggestions? i will take my code there, what should i leave here?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask "Can I improve the response time of this login service application by making parts of it asynchronous?" Just an idea. It seems a lot of what you are getting at is "is this code good enough for ...". Beyond perhaps pointing out glaring issues, answers to these questions tend to be speculative and opinion based which is off topic for this site

Comment: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: No.**

Async code doesn't make things "faster". Async code is just regular sync code with some extra capabilities to pause/resume operations. There's no speed gain. The purpose of async code is not speed, it's to achieve concurrency without the overhead of threads.

---

See these two functions in the following code:

```
def func1():
    data = get_data_from_database()
    return data


async def func2():
    data = await get_data_from_database()
    return data
```

`func1` is synchronous and `func2` is asynchronous. Both functions will have the same speed because they both have to wait for the database to return the data.

So, you can make your code async, but it won't result in any speed gain because the database will return the data at it's regular speed and only after that will your code be able to perform further actions.

---

And don't use SQLite with Tornado. It runs in the same Python process as your Tornado code. And since it's going to read and write data to/from disk, it will result in slower, blocking code which will block the whole Tornado server and result in poor performance. See below for an explanation of "Blocking Code".

Now, yes, you can make it asynchronous, by running it in a separate thread, but then why not just use a standalone database like PostgreSQL or MySQL in the first place?

---

**Blocking Code**

A code which stops the program from moving further or doing anything else is called blocking code.

Blocking code can be of any of the following types:

1. Network bound operations. For example you're making an http request, or a database request, this is a network bound operation and it is slower. And this results in blocking code because the code can't move forward until it gets the response.
2. Disk bound operations. For example if you read a file from the disk, it results in blocking code because if the disk is busy or slow, your code can't move forward until it gets the data from the disk.
3. CPU bound operations. For example doing really heavy calculations which take up significant CPU time. It will result in blocking code because the code can't move forward until it gets the result of the calculation from the CPU.

Asynchronous code is useful for network bound operations. For disk and CPU bound operations, synchronous code is better.